# Jk Flip Flop( Counter not Working)

Tags: counter, synchronous

I am having problems with simulation for this particular counter. below are all my diagram including truth table and multisim simulation. the problem is its only going from 0-4 and vice versa. It should go like 0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4. Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]My Kc is equal to 1 and ka is also equal to 1
A=m
b=Qa
c=Qb
d=Qc

[image]

[image]

Comment: why do you need `D` term for a counter that does not exceed a count of 4?

Comment: a is for up /down and d is for basically c in the present state.

Comment: You have put together a simulatable description of your design...run the simulation and look for the first instance when the actual behavior is different from the desired behavior. Don't try to debug by staring at the design.

Comment: why do you need up/down? ... did you include all information in your question?

Comment: its a up/down counter. i stated above that it goes from 0 to 4 then 4 to 0. so its a mod 5 up/down counter

Comment: not what you said .... you said that it should count 0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4 .... instead it counts 0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0 (which means that is bad) .... read your question and correct it

Comment: NOT gates U9 and U10 are connected to Vcc making their output 0. That makes U4 and U11 always output 0 too. AND gates U8, U12 and U17 are also connected to Vcc, making some of them NOPs. Your signals go back and forth all across the schematic. Consider reordering so that signals go from left to right with the least amount of wires going back. Placing the JKs vertical can help.